# Calling parent method and still hold the current variable

Tags: java, oop

I have a Model class. This Model has the method `loadModel`. It's there to load data from the database. I have many other models that extend `Model`. Now, I'm doing it like this

Model.java

```
public class Model {
    public String tablename = "";

    public void loadModel ( String id ) {
        System.out.println ( "Tablename is: " + this.tablename );
    }
}
```

User.java

```
public class User extends Model {
    public String tablename = "users";

    @Override
    public void loadModel ( String id ) {
        super.loadModel(id);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that the parent loadModel class would say "Tablename is users"? In PHP it would work like this, why not in Java? How does it work in Java to do that? Since I will have many Models that should extend Model and it would be easier to do it like this so I don't have to rewrite methods all the time.

**Update**

What the method should do is the following.

When I call the loadModel method I pass the ID of an entry. Like "5". Then I would call it like this
`loadModel("5")`. Now the method of users get called and this calls the parent method of the super class. Now the super class should do this

"SELECT * FROM " + this.tablename + " WHERE id=" + id;

I hope I cleared some confusin.

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Have a look at answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make design elegant, instead of making table name public, add an abstract method in Model call like

public abstract String getTableName();

Implement this abstract method to provide a table name in all subclasses.

In Model, use getTableName for printing.

```
public abstract class Model {
    public abstract String getTableName();

    public void loadModel ( String id ) {
        System.out.println ( "Tablename is: " + getTableName() );
    }
}

public class User extends Model {
    private String tablename = "users";

    public String getTableName()
    {
       return tablename;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadModel ( String id ) {
        super.loadModel(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String tablename = "users";
```

This refers to a different variable than the one Model is looking at.  You'd have to use a solution that either shares the variable in Model, or uses a method to return the value so subclasses can override it.

Model.java

```
public class Model {
  public String tablename = "";

  public void loadModel ( String id ) {
    System.out.println ( "Tablename is: " + getTableName());
  }
  public String getTableName() {
    return tablename;
  }
}
```

User.java

```
public class User extends Model {
  public String tablename = "users";

  @Override
  public void loadModel ( String id ) {
    super.loadModel(id);
  }

  @Override
  public String getTableName() {
    return tablename;
  }
}
```

This is a pretty common pattern.  Often I'd see Model and Model.getTableName declared as abstract as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way of doing it:

```
public class Model {
    private String tablename = "";

    protected String getTableName() {
        return tablename;
    }

    public void loadModel ( String id ) {
        System.out.println ( "Tablename is: " + getTableName());
    }
}

public class User extends Model {
    private String tablename = "users";

    @Override
    protected String getTableName() {
        return tablename;
    }
}
```

and if you were only going to instantiate User you could make Model abstract:

```
public abstract class Model {

    protected abstract String getTableName();

    public void loadModel ( String id ) {
        System.out.println ( "Tablename is: " + getTableName());
    }
}
```